# Read image pixels without Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, image

Is there a way to read pixels from Image without using Canvas and its getImageData method?
Canvas is HTML5 feature which isn't available in IE8 and lower.

Comment: You could always fetch the binary image data using Ajax and then write (or find, or commission) an image-processing library in JavaScript that converts binary image data into pixel data.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches

1. Polyfill canvas, e.g. http://flashcanvas.net/ (or [others](https://github.com/Modernizr/Modernizr/wiki/HTML5-Cross-browser-Polyfills#canvas)), not sure if any of these supports reading the pixel infos
2. Use a JPEG (assuming that's the format) decoder written in JS or compiled using [Emscripten](https://github.com/kripken/emscripten) (e.g. libjpeg)

Comment: I've seen these polyfills but they depend on flash player or silverlight. I contacted author of Kinectjs to see if this is possible in his library but I'm still waiting for an answer.